Capture and re-send packets from a game on Windows
I would like to capture a packet/message sent to the game's server, analyse the response and resend it maybe later ?
I come from web developement where I can simply copy a request inside the console of my browser and reuse it inside a JS script for exemple
Is that possible ? (I heard about tools like WireShark)
Thank you

I heard about tools like WireShark You should investigate those tools.
